# OrientDB Graph Traversal using java language

Tags: java, orientdb

I am new to OrientDb and have a graph DB, where the vertices are connected as :
Node1-[HAS_CHILD]->Node2-[HAS_CHILD]->Node3...(node4 and so on) and so on.
Now my question is, given Node3 or any node like node3, how do i traverse back till i reach Root Node(Node1). I have tried following code so far:

```
GremlinPipeline<Vertex,Vertex> pipe = new GremlinPipeline<>();
    pipe.start(node3).as("start").inE("HAS_CHILD").outV()
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you're trying to get outgoing vertices you can just use the *out()* function using edge's label:

```
GremlinPipeline<Vertex,Vertex> pipe = new GremlinPipeline<>();
pipe.start(node3).as("start").out("HAS_CHILD")
```

However, if you want to backtrack just change that out() to *in()*:

```
GremlinPipeline<Vertex,Vertex> pipe = new GremlinPipeline<>();
pipe.start(node3).as("start").in("HAS_CHILD")
```

[OrientDB Docs | SQL Functions - OUT](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/sql/SQL-Functions.html#out)

[OrientDB Docs | SQL Functions - IN](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/sql/SQL-Functions.html#in)

Comment: But that would give me the node present at 1 hop from node3. But i want to see which node is parent of node3 and so on till i reach root node.